# Make a chart with some values from my table

Tags: javascript, charts, playframework, amcharts

So I have a week since I am trying to solve this problem and I can't get it done .
I have this table :

```
<table id= "myTable" style="width:100%">
<tr  class="val">
    <th>value</th>
    @for((c,w)<- map){
    <td>@c</td>
     }
</tr>
<tr class="timp">
    <th>time</th>
    @for(k <- timeList){
        <td> @k</td> 
     }
</tr>
<tr class="data">
    <th>date</th> 
    @for(q <- dateList){ 
    <td>@q </td>
    }
 </tr>

</table>
```

And it looks like this : 
[image]

I want to draw a chart. ...
And on the `x` axe I want to have my date , and my hour ... and on the `y` my values.

I tried looping through my `td` elements ... I tried a lot of libraries ... but I can't  get my data ...

For example, now I am playing with amchart plugin . I have this code :

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/amcharts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/serial.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart;

            var chartData = [];

            AmCharts.ready(function () {
                // first we generate some random data
                generateChartData();

                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.pathToImages = "@routes.Assets.at("images/images/")";
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.categoryField = "date";

                // data updated event will be fired when chart is first displayed,
                // also when data will be updated. We'll use it to set some
                // initial zoom
                chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

                // AXES
                // Category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.parseDates = true; // in order char to understand dates, we should set parseDates to true
                categoryAxis.minPeriod = "mm"; // as we have data with minute interval, we have to set "mm" here.            
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.07;
                categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";

                // Value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.07;
                valueAxis.title = "Things Chart";
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPH
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.type = "line"; // try to change it to "column"
                graph.title = "red line";
                graph.valueField = "visits";
                graph.lineAlpha = 1;
                graph.lineColor = "#d1cf2a";
                graph.fillAlphas = 0.3; // setting fillAlphas to > 0 value makes it area graph
                chart.addGraph(graph);

                // CURSOR
                var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
                chartCursor.cursorPosition = "mouse";
                chartCursor.categoryBalloonDateFormat = "JJ:NN:SS, YYYY-MM-DD";
                chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

                // SCROLLBAR
                var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();

                chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });

            // generate some random data, quite different range 
            function generateChartData() {
                // current date
                var firstDate = new Date();
                // now set 1000 minutes back                 
                firstDate.setMinutes(firstDate.getDate() - 1000);

                // and generate 1000 data items
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
                    // each time we add one minute
                    newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + i);
                    // some random number      
                    var visits = Math.round(Math.random() * 40) + 10;
                    // add data item to the array                          
                    chartData.push({
                        date: newDate,
                        visits: visits
                    });
                }
            }

            // this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
            function zoomChart() {
                // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
                chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 40, chartData.length - 1);
            }
        </script>



<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-11">
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the `function generateChartData()` I tried to select the values from my table ... but when I am looping through my elements - the chart disappears ... that means I am not doing it right ... Here I have the example with the random elements, because I think my code it is not good and maybe this helps ...

So , how cand I do this ? Can it be done ?
Thank you !

[image: This is the chart I am talking about ... maybe some of you played with it...]

This is the chart I am talking about ... maybe some of you played with it...

But any other method that it will work it will be good for me  ...

Comment: When you call `chart.write("chartdiv");`, do you need to put a # in font of the ID? So you'd have `chart.write("#chartdiv");`

Comment: in the sample it works without  # ... it wont work with # ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your code which parses the HTML table into a JSON data format, I can't provide any insight into why it did not work. The chart not showing up indicates that most probably the resulting JSON was not constructed the way amCharts expects it to.

However, here's a function that does parse your table structure into a JSON format suitable for your chart:

```
function generateChartData() {

  // initialize empty array
  chartData = [];

  // get the table
  var table = document.getElementById( 'myTable' );

  // get table rows
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );

  // iterate through the <td> elements of the first row
  // and construct chart data out of other rows as well
  var values = rows[ 0 ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
  var times = rows[ 1 ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
  var dates = rows[ 2 ].getElementsByTagName( 'td' );
  for ( var x = 0; x < values.length; x++ ) {
    chartData.push( {
      "visits": values[ x ].innerHTML,
      "date": dates[ x ].innerHTML + " " + times[ x ].innerHTML
    } );
  }
}
```

And here's your chart and table as a working example:

http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/02590246bc91401ddb138e026b4cf075

Following is a list of changes I made from your original code:

1. Updated generateChartData function code to parse HTML table as a JSON;
2. Added `chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS";` line to indicate date/time format in data so that chart can correctly parse it; (without specifying date format it may not work correctly in some older browsers and string date/time)
3. Removed the pre-zoom event/function for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Sorry for piggybacking, but I can't seem to display the chart with this instruction. Here is the fiddle. Any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/LoLcn2vn/

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to change the `values` to `years`! Silly me. Updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/LoLcn2vn/1/